# ¿ como llamo de una variable un campo de la base de datos?

Tags: php, html, mysql

quiero extraer un dato de una tabla de base de datos por medio de una variable pero no me funciona

```
<?php
                  
                    $subasta = new Subasta();           
                    $subasta->setIdsubasta($idsubasta);
                    $rst = $subasta->Obtener();
                    $fotovendedor='uploads_img/user_uploads/'.$rst['userfoto2'];
                    $fotoarticulo='uploads_img/articulos_uploads/'.$rst['Ruta_Foto'];
                    $puja = new Puja();           
                    $puja->setIdsubasta($idsubasta);
                    $rst2 = $puja->PujaMayor();
                    $rst3 = $puja->ContarPujas();
                    $rst4 = $puja->ContarOfertantes();
                    $rst5 = $puja->PujasegundaMayor();
                    $incremento = $_POST["incremento"];//<-este dato de incremento pero en el codigo no me da error donde me da error es lo siguiente 
                    ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
como le tengo que hacer ocupo sacar el valor de incremento para sumarlo con otro valor pero no me sale el dato

este es formulario

````
<form method="POST" action="app/add_subasta.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-3 col-form-label" for="date-input"> <i class="icons cui-dollar"></i> Valor de incremento:</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="incremento" placeholder="Incremento" required onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event)">
                                        <span class="help-block">Ingrese un valor de incremento para la subasta</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div> <div class="card-footer">
                                                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" name = "editar" type="submit">
                                                  <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Guardar cambios</button>
                                                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="reset">
                                                  <i class="fa fa-ban"></i> Cancelar</button>
                                          </div>
</form>```

me pidieron la funcion de solonumeros en javascript
````

```
function soloNumeros(e) {
  var key = e.keyCode || e.which,
    tecla = String.fromCharCode(key).toLowerCase(),
    letras = "0123456789",
    especiales = [8, 37, 39, 46],
    tecla_especial = false;
  for (var i in especiales) {
    if (key == especiales[i]) {
      tecla_especial = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (letras.indexOf(tecla) == -1 && !tecla_especial) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

¿Qué podría hacer?, soy principiante en esto, me gustaría que me pudieran ayudar.
Desconozco el código que tengo que poner ¿Cómo debería escribir el código?
este es el codigo de addsubasta de ahi se envia a otro donde tengo las consultas

`````
                $subasta->setValorminimo($_POST['valorminimo']);
                $subasta->setIncrementos($_POST['incremento']);
                $subasta->setTiempoini($fechainicio);
                $subasta->setTiempofin($fechafin);
                $subasta->setEstado('Subasta');
                $subasta->setVendedor($_SESSION['username']);
                ````
`````

aqui tengo las consulta ala hora de insertar

```
   public function Registrar($articulo){ //REGISTRAR UNA SUBASTA CON SU ARTICULO
            try{
                $rst = $this->Incremento();
                $id = $rst['id']+1;
                $idart = $articulo->getIdarticulo();
                $sql = "INSERT INTO subasta(ID_Subasta, Valor_Minimo, incremento, Tiempo_Inicio, Tiempo_Fin,
                                            Estado, Username_Vendedor, ID_Articulo)
                                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
                $stm = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
                $result = $stm->execute(array($id, $this->getValorminimo(), $this->getIncrementos(),
                                              $this->getTiempoini(),$this->getTiempofin(), $this->getEstado(), 
                                              $this->getVendedor(), $idart));
                $stm->closeCursor(); //Cierra cursor MySQL
                unset($articulo);
                return $result;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $_SESSION['msgError1'] = 'Error al guardar: '.$e->getMessage();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola. Falta contexto en tu pregunta. ¿Cómo estás mandando el valor que intentas recuperar luego mediante `$_POST["incremento"]`?

Comment: @A.Cedano por medio de un formulario se ingresa el valor del incremento en la base de datos si se agrega

Comment: **@A.Cedano** o como te refieres

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrega a la pregunta el `html` de dicho formulario. Todo parece indicar que no estás recibiendo los datos correctamente por algún motivo o bien la etiqueta `name` no tiene el nombre `incremento`
, o bien el método del formulario no es `POST` sino `GET`... para depurar lo que estás recibiendo puedes poner temporalmente un `var_dump($_POST);`.

Comment: @A.Cedano entonces en lugar de esto` $incremento = $_POST["incremento"]` pongo esto ` $incremento = var_dump($_POST)` o como @A.Cedano

Comment: No, no es quitar una cosa y dejar otra, lo del `var_dump` es algo provisional, para verificar lo que estás recibiendo en el servidor. Viendo que llamas a una función Javascript: `soloNumeros()` conviene que muestres también esa función para ver qué es lo que haces ahí, no sé si usas Ajax o la API Fetch para mandar los datos al servidor ¿? Ese punto aún no aparece claro. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el código Javascript.

Comment: Iba a comentar que no veo un botón submit en el formulario, así que sería necesario ver el código de la función `solonumeros`. Haces ahí el envío del formulario?

Comment: tu form dice que lo envias a `app/add_subasta.php` pero tu error dice que es en `vista_subasta.php` ???

Comment: @Bryro ese form no se está enviando del modo normal, pues no tiene un botón de envío. Al parecer todo ocurre desde la función `soloNumeros()`, habría que ver el código en esa función. Es cierto que por coherencia si el form no se envía mediante el action no debería tener nada en ese atributo.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya edite y agregue el código de `solo números` y agregue la parte del boton submit del formulario

Comment: O sea que el form sí se envía mediante un botón submit. Es importante que no omitas parte relevante del código. Revisa lo que te comenta @Byro sobre la diferencia en el nombre del archivo .php que debería recibir los datos enviados. Por otra parte, ¿cómo se supone que el `input` adquiere un valor? Nunca asignas nada al atributo `value` del mismo.

Comment: ya pude gracias el error que en la consulta `SELECT` no agregaba el campo incremento por eso no salia @A.Cedano gracias